# Facebook and Twitter live feed in Android applications

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, cordova

I want show the live-feed of Facebook and Twitter in my android-applications.
Just like in this page . [espn.com](http://espn.go.com/nba/). How to do that?

Should i go for html , css in android.??

Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Facebook and tweeter live feed in Android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857817/facebook-and-tweeter-live-feed-in-android-applications)

Comment: @Guffa - that question was removed by its author and is no longer available.

Comment: @BryanH: I flagged this question as the duplicate, as the other question was posted first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should download the Facebook API and Twitter API and just create a nice regular layout of views that you populate with the data. E.g. a simple ListView or ScrollView that you add a template View with some text and image (if available in the post) using an Adapter. That way you could make it look excactly the way you want to and it's also quite simple. There are tutorials for how to use the API on the web sites https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk and http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage.